# Is there way in python to traverse a matrix in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following matrix:

```
from random import randint

n, m = 5, 7
matrix = [[randint(-9, 9) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

How I can traverse through this matrix with help of list comprehension, without own loops?

My aim to get list of elements which less than `k` and which is located at odd rows, in general I want to roll up this code to list comprehension:

```
sample = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if matrix[i][j] < k and i % 2 != 0:
            sample.append(matrix[i][j])
```

I tried to make it, but it doesn't work:

```
sample = [elem for elem in row for row in matrix if elem < k]
```

Comment: Could you make explicit what you are trying to accomplish? What have you tried and what you would like your finished result to look like?

You might want to look into (2d) numpy arrays since they give you much more functionality.

Comment: @Andre yea, you are right, but I want to know, I can do this or not with simple lists

Comment: @Steve has solved this problem already. I know you said you wanted a comprehension, but if you wanted a numpy solution you could have done `import numpy as np; matrix = np.array(matrix); sample = matrix[1::2][matrix[1::2] < k]`

Comment: @Ildar - Check out my new answer!  It points out something cool about Python that I just learned and that might have been THE TIDBIT you were looking for.  Don't you agree that it's the more correct answer?  If so, feel free to move your checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just doing some Python research and happened to see some code that led me to know that you can use nested for loops in list comprehensions.  Having this knowledge, and having just answered this question, I thought I owed it to the world to come and write a second answer.

I think this one is superior in that A) it doesn't use a module that has to be imported, and B) it's just simpler and cooler:

```
sample = [ matrix[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(m) if matrix[i][j] < k and i % 2 != 0 ]
```

So `if` statements nest in list comprehensions!  Who knew.

Comment: ohh, real, how I couldn't guess solution like this, it's really more simple, ty!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this does the same thing as your example, but in a list comprehension:

```
import itertools

sample = [ matrix[i][j] for (i, j) in itertools.product(range(n), range(m)) if matrix[i][j] < k and i % 2 != 0 ]
```